# How can I Include brackets in a PowerShell hash table value?

Tags: powershell

I can successfully make POST requests in Postman using this body in my call, which uses nested key pair values:

```
{
   "meta": null,
   "data": {
       "type": "spaces_schema"
       "attributes": {
           "spaces": ["space1", "space2"]
       }
   }  
}
```

I am transposing the call into PowerShell, and creating the body using a nested hash table. The call returns an error regarding the body when done in PowerShell:

```
$Body = @{
    "meta" = "null" 
    "data" = @{ 
         "type" = "spaces_schema"  
         "attributes" = @{
             "spaces" = ["space1", "space2"]
        }
    } 
}
```

The problem I am running into is the "spaces" attribute. I am not sure how to pass the brackets as literal characters in the hash table without wrapping them in quotes, since doing so puts out an error as well and interferes with the quotes used inside of the brackets.

Here is the error:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : {"errors":[{"additional_data":null,"detail":"Unhandled exception from route request: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"}]}
At C:\Users\{user}\Desktop\{Folder}\{Scriptname}.ps1:26 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -URI 'https://{URL} ...
```

Comment: Use `@("space1", "space2")` or just `"space1", "space2"` since you have more than one value so that element will be an array. (In json an array shows in between square brackets)

Comment: @Theo thank you. I gave it a try and it still returned an error though. I made the changes and ran the command ```$SpacesBody | ConvertTo-Json``` and it actually showed the contents of "spaces" without the brackets as well.

Comment: [ConvertTo-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-7.2) has a `-Depth` parameter that default to 2. Make that a higher number

Comment: @Theo that fixed the formatting. I now get the error ```Invoke-WebRequest : {"errors":[{"additional_data":null,"detail":"Type error: got an unexpected keyword argument"}]}``` so it must have something to do with the keys I'm using now. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying too hard to make the **object** look like JSON syntax.

As said, to define an element's value as array, you need to enclose it in `@()`. In Json syntax that would display inside square brackets.

Writing `"meta" = "null"` is wrong too, because you then define it as **string** with a literal value of `"null"`.
What you should do in the object is `meta = $null` which wil translate to JSON as `"meta": null`

In your case, the default `-Depth` setting of the ConvertTo-Json cmdlet is not deep enough, so you need to set that to a value of at least 3 (in the example you gave).

Try

```
$Body = @{
    meta = $null
    data = @{ 
         type = "spaces_schema"  
         attributes = @{
             spaces = @("space1", "space2")
        }
    } 
}

$Body | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3
```

Since you will be uploading this data using `Invoke-WebRequest` or `Invoke-RestMethod`, I would advice to add switch `-Compress` to the ConvertTo-Json cmdlet as well. This will return a less human readable json, but the payload will be smaller because all extra whitespace will be removed:

```
{"meta":null,"data":{"type":"spaces_schema","attributes":{"spaces":["space1","space2"]}}}
```